# How to fix infinity request useEffect hook?

Tags: reactjs, api

When I add [ ] to useEffect, the page doesn't reload after user action(for example add new post). But if let it go, I have request to the server every second.

```
useEffect(
    () => {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/task-list/')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setTodo(data))
    })
```

Comment: You should get what your looking for if you track the updated "add new post" in the useEffect dependency array. : useEffect(()=> {fetch..},[newPost])

Comment: Then pass a value of new post as a dependency in array dependency.

Comment: post a code pen or w.e its hard to see without seeing the rest of it